# Including images with a Jekyll theme

Tags: jekyll

When [creating a Jekyll theme](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/), how can I include images with the theme?

These can be background images, icons, social buttons, and **images that belongs to the theme and not to the site**.

I have tried adding a folder with images to the theme but the generated site (that's using the theme) doesn't serve it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not possible **yet**, expected to arrive with 3.3, see here:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5341